# Unable to display error message on angularJS login page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a spring boot application in which angularjs is configured, in an ajax call for authentication purpose, if the authentication fails, the error call back gets executed, in this error call back I am getting a error message as part of data which I have to display it on login page which is not working. Below is the error callback method

```
onerror = function(data){
           console.log(data); -- the output of data is as below 

"timestamp":1498971200809,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"check your password","path":"/demo/authenticate"}

           vm.error= true; // setting error to true
           vm.errMessage = data.message; // here data.message gives me 
                                            undefined

           $location.path("/customlogin");
       }
```

The customlogin.html code is

```
    <body ng-controller="ContactLoginCtrl as Contactctrl">

        <div ng-if="Contactctrl.error"> -- this is always evaluating false 
                    {{Contactctrl.errMessage}}
                </div>
   </body>
```

in the above snippet we are checking the error variable of the controller if its true (set in the error callback method) the I have to display the errMessage which is set in the error method callback shown above.

I am not getting what mistake I did please some body help me

ContactLoginCtrl.js

```
angular.module('baseApp')
.controller('ContactLoginCtrl', ['$scope','AuthenticateService','$location',function($scope,AuthenticateService,$location){
    console.log("in the controller")
   var vm =this;
    vm.error=false;
    vm.errMessage="";
    vm.authenticate = function(userModel){
        //alert(userModel.username);
        var userName = userModel.username;
        var password = userModel.password;
        //console.log(userName+password);
        var result = AuthenticateService.login(userName,password);
        result.success(onsuccess)
              .error(onerror);
    }



        onsuccess = function(data){

            var usernameResult = AuthenticateService.getCredentials();
            usernameResult.success(onusersuccess)
                           .error(onusererror);


        };
       onerror = function(data){

           vm.error= true;
           vm.errMessage = data.message;
           alert(vm.errMessage);
           $location.path("/customlogin");
       }



       onusersuccess = function(data){
           console.log("userData"+JSON.stringify(data))
            $location.path("/home");


        };

        onusererror = function(data){
             console.log(data);

        };
}]);
```

screenshot of the output of the console below

[image]

Comment: Please post whole code of controller

Comment: console result data and see if it contains "Message" field

Comment: @RohanKawade, the console result data contains message field below is the output {"timestamp":1498976864439,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"check your password","path":"/demo/authenticate"}

Comment: If my guess is correct, you are getting error from `onusererror` function but not from `onerror`. See, you also printing the `data` in `onusererror` and you are setting the value in `onerror`. That might be the issue

Comment: I think you should parse your result JSON....may be the service returns a result string

Comment: yes I parsed it but no use

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting the value in wrong function or in  the function that is not what you are intended to do. Set the values of `error` and `errMessage` in `onusererror`. As you said in comments, you are printing the value in `onusererror` that means you are getting `success` from `AuthenticateService.login(userName,password);` and there is no way of calling `onerror`

```
   onerror = function(data){

       vm.error= true;
       vm.errMessage = data.message;
       alert(vm.errMessage);
       $location.path("/customlogin");
   }



   onusersuccess = function(data){
       console.log("userData"+JSON.stringify(data))
        $location.path("/home");


    };

    onusererror = function(data){
         console.log(data);
         vm.error= true;
         vm.errMessage = data.message;
         alert(vm.errMessage);
         $location.path("/customlogin");

    };
```

Comment: changed the code as u said above , its the same problem

Comment: http://localhost:7001/demo/authenticate 401 (Unauthorized) -- this is authentication failed error , for this only i have to show the error message

Comment: Please tell me which function is running on error `onerror` or `onusererror`? Please observe correctly

Comment: you mention an `alert` in `onerror`. Is that working, means is that alerting?

Comment: yes the alert is working and below is the data being alerted {"timestamp":1498971200809,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"check your password","path":"/demo/authenticate"}

Comment: and in the next line you are redirecting the path right. remove this `$location.path("/customlogin");` and try

Comment: yes removed the the statement $location.path("/customlogin"), its the same error no change

Comment: Is it possible for you to reproduce the error in plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue

Comment: internally the service calls the spring security and hits ldap server for authentication so I may not reproduce it on plunkr

Comment: is that showing if there is no `ng-if` in the `div`? Going through all worst conditions. :P

Comment: post a screenshot of the console printing data in the question.

Comment: posted the screennshot of the console and alert, even if i remove the ng-if condition the message is not getting displayed

Comment: I don;t know why data.message is giving undefined when message is present in the data

Comment: check `url`. is that changing to `/customlogin`